# connecting to wifi using ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I would like to know how i can connect to wifi using ubuntu terminal...first i gave the command "iwconfig wlan0 essid  key " but then it said that it doesnt have permissions ..so i added the "sudo" tag and made the command as "sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid  key "...but something wierd is happening ...nothing is happening .... the terminal is not showing any output or anything....it is like getting ready to take the next command ..but not showing anything related to the wifi connection ..like ..you are connected or you have failed etc etc ... i am relatively new to linux ...so help needed ...and i know that i can connect to wifi using the top right icon and all ..but i want to do it through the terminal ..

thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for StackOverflow. I suggest you ask on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Have you looked at the 'nmcli' command line tool, that utilizes your network manager connections? It's easier than the iwconfig route.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run the commands ifconfig wlan0 up, iwconfig wlan0 essid name key password and dhclient wlan0, you need to be root. So, you have to put the word sudo before those commands (unless you're already logged in as root).

The password in the command iwconfig wlan0 essid name key password should be in hexadecimal. If you want to type the ASCII password, you would use iwconfig wlan0 essid name key s:password.

The command iwconfig wlan0 essid name key password only works with access points that use WEP as encryption. If the access point uses WPA/WPA2, you'll have to use another method to connect.